# Is any way to open app through speaking specfic word in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

i have an idea in which user speak specific word or sentence and then  app open.Is it is possible in iOS ?

Comment: Are you referring to a system level feature or adding this capability to an app?

Comment: Sure, it's possible. "Hey Siri, open <app name>."

Comment: Basically i want to ring in app against some word.

Answer (score 2):

At this point in time, Siri cannot be used in your app for a function like this. You can use the command, "open " from anywhere in iOS and the specified app will open! More information can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/sirikit/) about SiriKit.